# Jenkinsfile with ansibleplaybook using multiple inventory files

Tags: ansible, jenkins-pipeline

When I need to include multiple inventory files using ansible-playbook in cli y usually use:

**ansible-playbook -i inventory/dev-hosts -i inventory/staging-hosts playbooks/run.yml**

Now I want to do this, but  in a Jenkinsfile . I´m using the following code:

```
stage('1') {
  steps {
     ansiColor('xterm') {
     ansiblePlaybook([
        colorized: true,
        inventory: inventory/dev-hosts ,  inventory/staging-hosts , 
        playbook: playbooks/run.yml 
        ])
      }
    }
}
```

But this not working. I can´t find information how to do this using Jenkinsfile. Any idea on how to solve it ?

Comment: Did you try without the trailing comma ? As you wrote it, chances are your current value is interpreted as an inline list of host names. Meanwhile, after looking at the build step form, the pipeline syntax help and the online plugin documentation, I'm quite sure this is a missing feature in jenkins. You might want to file an issue in the [plugin bug tracker](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ansible/#issues)

Comment: Please do not spread necessary info to answer your question over volatile comments: edit your question. And as explained earlier, I'm almost sure the jenkins ansiblePlaybook plugin does not support multiple inventories.

Comment: Ok Zeitounator. Thanks. Case closed.